# Is there a way to enter command line mode for a single command directly from insert mode?

Tags: command-line, insert-mode

I'd like to go directly into command line mode from insert mode, enter a single command (say `:r !date` which inserts the date) and then go immediately back into insert mode.

Basically something similar to the Ctrl-o command for entering normal mode for a single command then returning to insert mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe

```
<C-o>:r !date
```

will work